# YouTube Title, Share, Watch Button Removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

When I try to use video as a background my website the title and buttons appear at the top of the Youtube video. I want the title, watch and share button removed from the top of the Youtube embed. I've tried everything but nothing works.

I have attached my code. I tried to inject it with jQuery but no luck at all.

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5iNr0Tp13hY?mode=opaque&rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0&controls=0&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

```js
$('iframe').load(function() {
  $('iframe').contents().find("head").append($("<style type='text/css'>  .ytp-chrome-top.ytp-show-watch-later-title.ytp-share-button-visible.ytp-show-share-title.ytp-show-cards-title { display: none !important; } </style>"));
});
```

Comment: disable it from youtube embed code :)

Comment: youtube depricates showinfo parameter from september 2018, so that will not work

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#modestbranding

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an iFrame, use the [jquery.mb.YTPlayer](https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer), it's way easier.

Call the .js file to your HTML

`<script src="style/js/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.js"></script>`

And call the video with

`<div id="P1" class="player video-container" data-property="{videoURL:'https://www.youtube.com/watch?XXXXXXX',containment:'#video', autoPlay:true, showControls:false, mute:true, startAt:6, opacity:1, loop:1}"></div>`

`showControls:false` hide the controls, you have all the options in the documentation.